# Problems logging in using safari and Identity Server 4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

Some of our customers are having problems logging onto our site using Safari.
We have 3 sites, Main,Login and API, they are all running .NET Core 2.1.
Login is using Identity Server 4 with OIDC.

For the customer: They login in and then the page turn white.
Looking in the log it seems to log in, redirect to the main site, the main site redirects back to the login site (because it thinks the user is not authenticated) the login in site thinks they are logged in and redirects to the main site and gets stuck in a loop.

I have seen that Safari cookie size might be an issue  I changed to MemoryCacheTicketStore to reduce cookie size, did not help. 
One particular customer gets this problem 2-6 tries, then on the next try it works.

We have many customers that use Safari without any problems so it is not a problem for all customers.
I haven't been successful in reproducing the problem either.

Any suggestions on a solution or perhaps how to dig deeper into the problem?
/Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I have found a topic that explains a reason why IdentityServer has issues in Safari. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1278. Unfortunately, haven't found a proper decision yet.